# How to perform passwordless user/admin authentication using both email and sms in aws cognito?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am working on a personal project and having difficulties with implementing user passwordless authentication in aws. I have searched for a few different similar answers but have not been able to get answers. I have worked with a few services on aws before but cognito is giving me headache for quite some time. AWS CDK is being used in backend along with [serverless-stack](https://docs.serverless-stack.com/) so as to create our serverless backend.
**The code repo can be found here: [Link](https://github.com/pineapple45/aws-cognito-passwordless-auth).**

---

Ok, so first I will show what my implementaion is till now and then I will explain what problem I am experiencing.

IMPLEMENTATION:
I am using aws cdk for creating my server resources. I want to login users and admins. If admins login UI should change accordingly and they should be able to make other users admin if they want.

I have created my frontend in react and it looks something like this:

```
/*login.tsx*/
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Tabs, Tab, Form, Spinner, Button, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Input from './components/Input';
import PhoneNumberInput from 'react-phone-number-input/input';

import { Auth, Analytics, Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import Home from './components/home';
import config from './aws-amplify-config';

Amplify.configure(config);

const NOTSIGNIN = 'You are NOT logged in';
const SIGNEDIN = 'You have logged in successfully';
const SIGNEDOUT = 'You have logged out successfully';
const WAITINGFOROTP = 'Enter OTP number';
const VERIFYNUMBER = 'Verifying number (Country code +XX needed)';
const VERIFYEMAIL = 'Verifying email';

const App = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Welcome to AWS Amplify Demo');
  const [user, setUser] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [showOtpForm, setShowOtpForm] = useState(false);
  const password = Math.random().toString(10) + 'Abc#';

  const verifyAuth = () => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((user) => {
        setUser(user);
        setMessage(SIGNEDIN);
        setSession(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        setMessage(NOTSIGNIN);
      });
  };

  const signOut = () => {
    if (user) {
      Auth.signOut();
      setUser(null);
      setOtp(null);
      setMessage(SIGNEDOUT);
    } else {
      setMessage(NOTSIGNIN);
    }
  };

  const signIn = () => {
    console.log('signin triggered');
    setMessage(VERIFYEMAIL);
    console.log(user, email, password);

    Auth.signIn(email!)
      .then((result) => {
        setSession(result);
        setMessage(WAITINGFOROTP);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        if (e.code === 'UserNotFoundException') {
          signUp();
        } else if (e.code === 'UsernameExistsException') {
          setMessage(WAITINGFOROTP);
          signIn();
        } else {
          console.log(e.code);
          console.error(e);
        }
      });
  };

  const signUp = async () => {
    console.log('signup triggered');
    const result = await Auth.signUp({
      username: email as string,
      password,
      attributes: {
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber === null ? '' : phoneNumber,
        address: '',
      },
    }).then(() => signIn());
    return result;
  };

  const verifyOtp = () => {
    Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(session, otp!.toString())
      .then((user) => {
        setUser(user);
        setMessage(SIGNEDIN);
        setSession(null);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        signIn();
        setMessage(err.message);
        setOtp(null);
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  const emailHandler = (email: string | null) => {
    setEmail(email);
  };

  const phoneNumberHandler = (number: number | null) => {
    setPhoneNumber(number);
  };

  const otpHandler = (otpRecieved: number | null) => {
    setOtp(otpRecieved);
  };

  const initiateOTPrequest = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // initiate OTP request here
    e.preventDefault();
    signIn();
    setShowOtpForm(true);
  };

  const initiateAuth = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // initiate login proess here
    e.preventDefault();
    // setOtp(null)
    verifyOtp();
    console.log(otp);
    setShowOtpForm(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Ready to auth');
    // Auth.currentCredentials();
    setTimeout(verifyAuth, 1500);
    Analytics.autoTrack('session', {
      enable: true,
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('current user is', user);
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(email);
  }, [email]);

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <Container>
        {showOtpForm ? (
          <Form onSubmit={(e) => initiateAuth(e)}>
            <br />
            <Input
              controlId="otpInput"
              inputType="number"
              label="OTP"
              placeholder="Enter otp"
              inputCall={otpHandler}
            />
            <br />
            <p>OTP not received ? Resend OTP</p>
            <Button type="submit">LOGIN</Button>
          </Form>
        ) : (
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey="login-with-email">
            {/* sign up with email form */}
            <Tab eventKey="login-with-email" title="email">
              <Form onSubmit={(e) => initiateOTPrequest(e)}>
                <Input
                  controlId="loginFormEmail"
                  inputType="email"
                  label="Email address"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  inputCall={emailHandler}
                />

                <Button type="submit">GET OTP</Button>
              </Form>
            </Tab>
            {/* sign up with phone number form */}
            <Tab eventKey="login-with-phone-number" title="phone number">
              <Form onSubmit={(e) => initiateOTPrequest(e)}>
                <PhoneNumberInput
                  className="form-control"
                  country="IN"
                  international
                  withCountryCallingCode
                  value={phoneNumber}
                  onChange={phoneNumberHandler}
                />
                <Button type="submit">GET OTP</Button>
                <br />
              </Form>
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        )}
        <p>{message}</p>
      </Container>
    );
  } else {
    return <Home signOut={signOut} />;
  }
};

export default App;
```

The backend overview is something like this:

[image: cognito-backend-overview]

Now code for my cognito stack looks like this:

```
/*cognito-stack*/
import { CfnOutput, RemovalPolicy } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as sst from '@serverless-stack/resources';
import * as cognito from '@aws-cdk/aws-cognito';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as path from 'path';
import { NodejsFunction } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
import { VerifySesEmailAddress } from '@seeebiii/ses-verify-identities';

export default class CognitoStack extends sst.Stack {
  constructor(scope: sst.App, id: string, props?: sst.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const createAuthChallengeTrigger = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'create-auth-challenge',
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(6),
        handler: 'handler',
        entry: path.join(
          __dirname,
          '../../src/handlers/cognito-handlers/create-auth-challenge.ts'
        ),
        bundling: { externalModules: ['aws-sdk'] },
      }
    );

    const defineAuthChallengeTrigger = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'define-auth-challenge',
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(6),
        handler: 'handler',
        entry: path.join(
          __dirname,
          '../../src/handlers/cognito-handlers/define-auth-challenge.ts'
        ),
        bundling: { externalModules: ['aws-sdk'] },
      }
    );

    const postAuthenticationTrigger = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'post-authentication',
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(6),
        handler: 'handler',
        entry: path.join(
          __dirname,
          '../../src/handlers/cognito-handlers/post-authentication.ts'
        ),
        bundling: { externalModules: ['aws-sdk'] },
      }
    );

    const preSignUpTrigger = new NodejsFunction(this, 'pre-sign-up', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
      memorySize: 1024,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(6),
      handler: 'handler',
      entry: path.join(
        __dirname,
        '../../src/handlers/cognito-handlers/pre-sign-up.ts'
      ),
      bundling: { externalModules: ['aws-sdk'] },
    });

    const verifyAuthChallengeResponseTrigger = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'verify-auth-challenge-response',
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(6),
        handler: 'handler',
        entry: path.join(
          __dirname,
          '../../src/handlers/cognito-handlers/verify-auth-challenge-response.ts'
        ),
        bundling: { externalModules: ['aws-sdk'] },
      }
    );

    // USERPOOL
    const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'cognito-user-pool', {
      selfSignUpEnabled: true,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      accountRecovery: cognito.AccountRecovery.PHONE_AND_EMAIL,
      userVerification: {
        emailStyle: cognito.VerificationEmailStyle.CODE,
      },
      autoVerify: {
        email: true,
        phone: true,
      },
      standardAttributes: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          mutable: true,
        },
        phoneNumber: {
          required: true,
          mutable: true,
        },
        address: {
          required: false,
          mutable: true,
        },
      },
      signInAliases: {
        email: true,
        phone: true,
      },
      customAttributes: {
        country: new cognito.StringAttribute({ mutable: true }),
        city: new cognito.StringAttribute({ mutable: true }),
        isAdmin: new cognito.StringAttribute({ mutable: true }),
      },
      lambdaTriggers: {
        createAuthChallenge: createAuthChallengeTrigger,
        defineAuthChallenge: defineAuthChallengeTrigger,
        postAuthentication: postAuthenticationTrigger,
        preSignUp: preSignUpTrigger,
        verifyAuthChallengeResponse: verifyAuthChallengeResponseTrigger,
      },
    });

    // USERPOOL-CLIENT
    const userPoolClient = new cognito.UserPoolClient(this, 'UserPoolClient', {
      userPool,
      readAttributes: new cognito.ClientAttributes()
        .withStandardAttributes({
          givenName: true,
          familyName: true,
          email: true,
          emailVerified: true,
          address: true,
          birthdate: true,
          gender: true,
          locale: true,
          middleName: true,
          fullname: true,
          nickname: true,
          phoneNumber: true,
          phoneNumberVerified: true,
          profilePicture: true,
          preferredUsername: true,
          profilePage: true,
          timezone: true,
          lastUpdateTime: true,
          website: true,
        })
        .withCustomAttributes(...['country', 'city', 'isAdmin']),

      writeAttributes: new cognito.ClientAttributes()
        .withStandardAttributes({
          givenName: true,
          familyName: true,
          email: true,
          emailVerified: false,
          address: true,
          birthdate: true,
          gender: true,
          locale: true,
          middleName: true,
          fullname: true,
          nickname: true,
          phoneNumber: true,
          profilePicture: true,
          preferredUsername: true,
          profilePage: true,
          timezone: true,
          lastUpdateTime: true,
          website: true,
        })
        .withCustomAttributes(...['country', 'city']),

      authFlows: {
        custom: true,
        userSrp: true,
      },

      supportedIdentityProviders: [
        cognito.UserPoolClientIdentityProvider.COGNITO,
      ],

      preventUserExistenceErrors: true,
    });

    const createAuthChallengePolicyStatement = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ['ses:SendEmail', 'ses:SendRawEmail'],
      resources: ['*'],
    });

    createAuthChallengeTrigger.role?.attachInlinePolicy(
      new iam.Policy(this, 'create-auth-challenge-trigger-policy', {
        statements: [createAuthChallengePolicyStatement],
      })
    );

    // IDENTITY-POOL
    const identityPool = new cognito.CfnIdentityPool(this, 'identitypool', {
      allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true,
      // identityPoolName: `${STACK_PREFIX}-${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT}`,
      cognitoIdentityProviders: [
        {
          clientId: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
          providerName: userPool.userPoolProviderName,
        },
      ],
    });

    const isUserCognitoGroupRole = new iam.Role(this, 'users-group-role', {
      description: 'Default role for authenticated users',
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(
        'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com',
        {
          StringEquals: {
            'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref,
          },
          'ForAnyValue:StringLike': {
            'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated',
          },
        },
        'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
      ),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          'service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
        ),
      ],
    });

    const isAnonymousCognitoGroupRole = new iam.Role(
      this,
      'anonymous-group-role',
      {
        description: 'Default role for anonymous users',
        assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(
          'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com',
          {
            StringEquals: {
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref,
            },
            'ForAnyValue:StringLike': {
              'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated',
            },
          },
          'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
        ),
        managedPolicies: [
          iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
            'service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
          ),
        ],
      }
    );

    const isAdminCognitoGroupRole = new iam.Role(this, 'admins-group-role', {
      description: 'Default role for administrator users',
      assumedBy: new iam.FederatedPrincipal(
        'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com',
        {
          StringEquals: {
            'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud': identityPool.ref,
          },
          'ForAnyValue:StringLike': {
            'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr': 'authenticated',
          },
        },
        'sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
      ),
      managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
          'service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
        ),
      ],
    });

    new cognito.CfnUserPoolGroup(this, 'users-group', {
      groupName: 'Users',
      userPoolId: userPool.userPoolId,
      description: 'The default group for authenticated users',
      precedence: 3, // the role of the group with the lowest precedence - 0 takes effect and is returned by cognito:preferred_role
      roleArn: isUserCognitoGroupRole.roleArn,
    });

    new cognito.CfnUserPoolGroup(this, 'admins-group', {
      groupName: 'Admins',
      userPoolId: userPool.userPoolId,
      description: 'The group for admin users with special privileges',
      precedence: 2, // the role of the group with the lowest precedence - 0 takes effect and is returned by cognito:preferred_role
      roleArn: isAdminCognitoGroupRole.roleArn,
    });

    new cognito.CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(
      this,
      'identity-pool-role-attachment',
      {
        identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
        roles: {
          authenticated: isUserCognitoGroupRole.roleArn,
          unauthenticated: isAnonymousCognitoGroupRole.roleArn,
        },
        roleMappings: {
          mapping: {
            type: 'Token',
            ambiguousRoleResolution: 'AuthenticatedRole',
            identityProvider: `cognito-idp.${
              cdk.Stack.of(this).region
            }.amazonaws.com/${userPool.userPoolId}:${
              userPoolClient.userPoolClientId
            }`,
          },
        },
      }
    );

    new VerifySesEmailAddress(this, 'SesEmailVerification', {
      emailAddress: process.env.SES_FROM_ADDRESS as string,
    });

    // Export values
    new CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolId', {
      value: userPool.userPoolId,
      exportName: 'UserPoolId',
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, 'UserPoolClientId', {
      value: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
      exportName: 'UserPoolClientId',
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, 'IdentityPoolId', {
      value: identityPool.ref,
      exportName: 'IdentityPoolId',
    });
  }
}
```

Now my trigger handlers as defined in above image are as follows:

1. pre-signup-trigger-handler

```
/*pre-signup-trigger-handler*/
import { PreSignUpTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: PreSignUpTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  console.log('event from pre-signup', event);
  event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

  // Set the email as verified if it is in the request
  if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
  }

  // Set the phone number as verified if it is in the request
  if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty('phone_number')) {
    event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
  }
  return event;
};
```

2. create-auth-challenge-trigger-handler

```
/*create-auth-challenge-trigger-handler*/
import { CreateAuthChallengeTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { randomDigits } from 'crypto-secure-random-digit';
import { SES, SNS } from 'aws-sdk';

const ses = new SES();

export const handler: CreateAuthChallengeTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  console.log('event for cognito createAuthChallenge', event);
  let secretLoginCode: string;

  if (!event.request.session || !event.request.session.length) {
    // This is a new auth session
    // Generate a new secret login code and mail it to the user
    secretLoginCode = randomDigits(6).join('');

    await sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, secretLoginCode);
  } else {
    // There's an existing session. Don't generate new digits but
    // re-use the code from the current session. This allows the user to
    // make a mistake when keying in the code and to then retry, rather
    // then needing to e-mail the user an all new code again.
    const previousChallenge = event.request.session.slice(-1)[0];
    secretLoginCode =
      previousChallenge.challengeMetadata!.match(/CODE-(\d*)/)![1];
  }

  // This is sent back to the client app
  event.response.publicChallengeParameters = {
    email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
  };

  // Add the secret login code to the private challenge parameters
  // so it can be verified by the "Verify Auth Challenge Response" trigger
  event.response.privateChallengeParameters = { secretLoginCode };

  // Add the secret login code to the session so it is available
  // in a next invocation of the "Create Auth Challenge" trigger
  event.response.challengeMetadata = `CODE-${secretLoginCode}`;

  return event;
};

async function sendEmail(emailAddress: string, secretLoginCode: string) {
  const params: SES.SendEmailRequest = {
    Destination: { ToAddresses: [emailAddress] },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `<html><body><p>This is your secret login code:</p>
                           <h3>${secretLoginCode}</h3></body></html>`,
        },
        Text: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `Your secret login code: ${secretLoginCode}`,
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'Your secret login code',
      },
    },
    Source: process.env.SES_FROM_ADDRESS as string,
  };
  await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
}

async function sendSMS(phoneNumber: number, secretLoginCode: string) {
  //sns sms
  const sns = new SNS({ region: 'us-east-1' });
  await sns.publish(
    {
      Message: 'your otp: ' + secretLoginCode,
      PhoneNumber: phoneNumber.toString(),
      MessageStructure: 'string',
      MessageAttributes: {
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
          DataType: 'String',
          StringValue: 'AMPLIFY',
        },
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
          DataType: 'String',
          StringValue: 'Transactional',
        },
      },
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        console.log(data);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`SMS sent to ${phoneNumber} and otp = ${secretLoginCode}`);
      return data;
    }
  );
}
```

3. verify-auth-challenge-trigger-handler

```
/*verify-auth-challenge-trigger-handler*/
import { VerifyAuthChallengeResponseTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: VerifyAuthChallengeResponseTriggerHandler = async (
  event
) => {
  const expectedAnswer =
    event.request.privateChallengeParameters!.secretLoginCode;
  if (event.request.challengeAnswer === expectedAnswer) {
    event.response.answerCorrect = true;
  } else {
    event.response.answerCorrect = false;
  }
  return event;
};
```

4. define-auth-challenge-trigger-handler

```
/*define-auth-challenge-trigger-handler*/
import { DefineAuthChallengeTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: DefineAuthChallengeTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.find(
      (attempt) => attempt.challengeName !== 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE'
    )
  ) {
    // We only accept custom challenges; fail auth
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = true;
  } else if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.length >= 3 &&
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === false
  ) {
    // The user provided a wrong answer 3 times; fail auth
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = true;
  } else if (
    event.request.session &&
    event.request.session.length &&
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeName === 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE' && // Doubly stitched, holds better
    event.request.session.slice(-1)[0].challengeResult === true
  ) {
    // The user provided the right answer; succeed auth
    event.response.issueTokens = true;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
  } else {
    // The user did not provide a correct answer yet; present challenge
    event.response.issueTokens = false;
    event.response.failAuthentication = false;
    event.response.challengeName = 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE';
  }

  return event;
};
```

5. post-auth-trigger-handler

```
/* post-auth-trigger-handler */

import { PostAuthenticationTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from 'aws-sdk';

const cup = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

export const handler: PostAuthenticationTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  if (event.request.userAttributes.email_verified !== 'true') {
    const params: CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AdminUpdateUserAttributesRequest =
      {
        UserPoolId: event.userPoolId,
        UserAttributes: [
          {
            Name: 'email_verified',
            Value: 'true',
          },
        ],
        Username: event.userName!,
      };
    await cup.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params).promise();
  }
  return event;
};
```

I am having trouble creating users during the signup process. I get the following error:

> code: "UserLambdaValidationException"
> message: "CreateAuthChallenge failed with error 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'destination' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null."
> name: "UserLambdaValidationException"

[image]

I know it means that the destination feild in SES.sendEmail() function is getting a null value while providing the params value. But I am not able to figure out how that value is getting turned to null when I am sending a non-null value from my frontend as you can see in the signIn() function. In addition this problem I have a few more problems:

1. Right now I am trying to make it work for sending OTP via email only. Although I have added the code for making it work with SNS service, I don't know where I will decide if the user has provided email or a phone number and depending upon that decide to send email or sms message ?
2. Also I need admins to manage the site. I have a few options in mind but not sure which option to go with. Each seems viable but
   2nd one requires a bit of more work. So here are the options:

   1. We add isAdmin as a standard attribute ( which I am doing right now ) and on the basis of that
      check weather a logged in user is admin or not ?
   2. We create another separate way of authenticating admins only ( for eg: username and password)?

I am sorry if the question became too long but this was the only way I could explain. I have tried searching a lot but did not found any good solutions. There are too many things happening and I have been really struggling to put all these bits and pieces together. Right now my code may not be that optimised but I am just trying to get it all work together.
**Code repo: [Link](https://github.com/pineapple45/aws-cognito-passwordless-auth)**
It would be really awesome if anyone could answer my queries. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is going on in your post auth trigger handler? Why does it hold the same code as your define auth challenge handler?

Comment: is there no typescript error here, `await sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, secretLoginCode);`? `event.request.userAttributes.email` is possibly undefined.

Comment: @AndrewGillis I apologise it was a mistake on my behalf. I have updated the code above in post-auth-trigger handler. The code in repo is correct though.

Comment: @AndrewGillis it does not show any typescript error.